# How to configure Logic Apps to probe Azure default DNS resolver (168.63.129.16)

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation, azure-alerts

Is there a way to set up Logic App, and have it configured in such a way that it probes the Azure DNS resolver (168.63.129.16) all time. If no response for certain interval, then an alert will be triggered to the specified notification group?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have this code:
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 168.63.129.16 -Port 80
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 168.63.129.16 -Port 443
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -Method GET -Uri http://168.63.129.16/?comp=versions

But how do I integrate in logic apps, that it probes the Azure DNS resolver (168.63.129.16) all time. If no response for certain interval, then an alert will be triggered to the specified notification group?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [HTTP action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) to call your endpoint and based on the response you can decide whether you want to send the email or not to your email group.

Work Flow:
[Recurrence trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence?tabs=consumption) --> [HTTP action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) --> [Send Email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-(v2))